# Foursquare callback error Uncaught exception

Tags: exception, callback, foursquare

I use foursquare API in an application. I have no issues when I run the app on my local machine but on a server I get this error after the user allows the app and is redirected to the callback url.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'EpiFoursquareException'
in /home/content/40/9029540/html/earlybirds/test/lib/EpiFoursquare.php:252
Stack trace:
#0 /home/content/40/9029540/html/earlybirds/test/lib/EpiFoursquare.php(208): EpiFoursquareException::raise(Object(EpiCurlManager), false) 
#1 /home/content/40/9029540/html/earlybirds/test/lib/EpiFoursquare.php(196): EpiFoursquareJson->__get('response')
#2 /home/content/40/9029540/html/earlybirds/test/callback.php(45): EpiFoursquareJson->offsetGet('access_token')
#3 {main} thrown in /home/content/40/9029540/html/earlybirds/test/lib/EpiFoursquare.php on line 252
```

Anyone knows the reason?
I use PHP and mysql

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you send the redirect_uri param when building your auth url and that it matches the one on the APP details page. I had to make two apps, one for testing locally and one for testing on my dev server which had, of course, a different URL.